# Why is my Leaflet JS App Canvas moving around?

Tags: leaflet

I have an Leaflet JS app, and when a user clicks on the canvas, the entire world is able to move causing the unsightly gray background to be shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/nos5gbjh/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use latlng fit to bounds.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds